# Match regex in javascript and filter out a character

Tags: javascript, match

I have a string and I want to return word after the given search parameter

my string is :

```
id=1845&type=edit&selectedMessage=3409
```

and í have used `=(\w+)`
it returns : `=1845`, `=edit`, `=3409`

I want to return without `=` sign

Comment: You haven't shown your current javascript code. Please post a snippet.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing this for, regex may be the wrong approach. For example, if this is javascript in a page you could do `let here = new URL(window.location)` then it's easy to get the parameters w/o using regex, such as: `let recId = here.searchParams.get('id')` and `let operation = here.searchParams.get('type')`

Answer (score 3):

You can use look behind to filter out the equal sign.

```js
let string = 'id=1845&type=edit&selectedMessage=3409';

let result = string.match(/(?<==)\w+/g)

console.log(result);
```

Here is a pretty good [explanation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Basically, you need to match `=` as a starting point, but it won't be included in the final output.

`(?<=...)` is the format for the positive lookbehind.

Comment: @LatracheAbdelfettah if it worked maybe you want to upvote this and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `"string".replace( "=", "" );`.

It´s quick and dirty, but it should do the job.

Comment: thanks, now i'm using this approach, but i want a clean regex parameter to not use slice().

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `[^=]=(\w+)` does the trick.

For future reference, I recommend using something like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for troubleshooting regex issues.

Comment: This includes the equals sign and the character before it, which is not what is required by the person who asked the question. See https://regexr.com/5bl5b for the example.